# Definitions of solvable group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, p-groups, solvable-groups

A solvable group seems to be variously defined as one with a *composition* series where all the composition factors are Abelian, or as one with a *subnormal* series where all the quotients are Abelian. Unlike with the first definition, this definition does not explicitly seem to require that the quotients be simple. Are they nonetheless equivalent?

Similarly, when looking at e.g. proofs that finite $p$-groups are solvable, I have seen the inductive argument which constructs a subnormal series with all the quotients Abelian but they never seem to show that the quotients are also simple. Why? Can one give a proof which does show that they are simple, and therefore complies with the composition series definition of solvable?

Thanks in advance for assistance.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_series#For_groups), a composition series is a subnormal series. Conversely, a subnormal series of maximal length is a composition series.

Comment: And [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group#Definition) defines a solvable group as one with a subnormal series whose quotient groups are abelian. I'm not sure if either of these comments are helpful.

Comment: @Carlo Well, my point is that the definition I have been given, and which is found in some sources but not others, is that of a *composition* rather than just a subnormal series where the quotients are Abelian. E.g. http://www-math.mit.edu/~dav/simplegroups.pdf: "a group is solvable if the factor groups of its composition series are all abelian", vs. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SolvableGroup.html: "a solvable group is a group having a normal series such that each normal factor is Abelian".

Comment: and @Carlo The answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3417303/different-definitions-for-solvable-groups seems to suggest that one gets from the normal series definition to the composition series definition by "refining" the normal series, but I didn't really understand most of the answer.

Comment: Yes, that is a standard technique in commutative algebra. Essentially, the idea is that if you are handed a subnormal series that is not a composition series, then you can extend it to a composition series by "stretching" it. Like Eric suggests, for each abelian quotient group $H_{i + 1} / H_i$ in the subnormal series, you can look at its composition series. Considering that the identity subgroup of $H_{i + 1} / H_i$ can be identified with $H_i$ by the Fourth Isomorphism Theorem, you obtain a chain of groups $H_i \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq H_{i + 1}$ each which is normal in the next.

Comment: But presumably we would need each group in the chain $H_i \subsetneq \dotsb \subsetneq H_{i+1}$ to be *maximally* normal in the next in order for it to be a composition series? How do you show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that a composition series is by definition a subnormal series, hence a composition series in which all of the factor groups are abelian is a subnormal series in which all of the factor groups are abelian. Conversely, a subnormal series of maximal length is a composition series by definition. Ultimately, therefore, it suffices to show that any subnormal series whose factor groups are abelian gives rise to (or more specifically, can be extended to) a subnormal series of maximal length.

**Edit:** As two users have noted in the comments below, the following argument holds when $G$ is a finite group. For instance, if $\mathbb Z$ had a composition series $$0 \triangleleft H_1 \triangleleft \cdots \triangleleft H_n = \mathbb Z,$$ then $0 \subsetneq H_1$ is a maximal strict normal subgroup of $H_1,$ hence $H_1$ must be a simple subgroup of $\mathbb Z.$ Considering that every subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ is cyclic, there exists an integer $n$ such that $H_1 = n \mathbb Z.$ But then, $2n \mathbb Z$ is a subgroup of $H_1$ --- a contradiction. Consequently, no infinite cyclic group has a composition series. That $G$ is finite is assumed in the answer linked in the comments above, and it is explicitly mentioned in the original post, hence we may assume for our purposes that $G$ is finite.

To this end, let $1 = H_1 \trianglelefteq H_2 \trianglelefteq \cdots \trianglelefteq H_n = G$ be a subnormal series such that for each integer $1 \leq i \leq n - 1,$ we have that $H_{i + 1} / H_i$ is abelian. Given that this has maximal length (i.e., all of the inclusions are strict and $H_i$ is a maximal strict normal subgroup of $H_{i + 1}$), we are done. Otherwise, we may assume that there exists an integer $i$ such that $H_i$ is contained in another normal subgroup of $H_{i + 1}.$ By hypothesis that $H_{i + 1} / H_i$ is abelian, it is solvable and therefore must have a composition series in which all of its factor groups are abelian. Explicitly, our composition series is $$1 = K_1 \triangleleft K_2 \triangleleft \cdots \triangleleft K_m = H_{i + 1} / H_i$$ with $K_{j + 1} / K_j$ is abelian for each integer $1 \leq j \leq m - 1,$ where $\triangleleft$ denotes strict inclusion as a normal subgroup. By the Fourth Isomorphism Theorem, we can identify $1$ with the subgroup $H_i$ of $G.$ Likewise, each of the subgroups $K_j$ gives rise to a strict inclusion of subgroups $N_j \triangleleft N_{j + 1}$ of $G$ that contain $H_i.$ We can therefore unravel this composition series as $H_i \subsetneq N_1 \subsetneq N_2 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq H_{i + 1}$ within our original subnormal series of $G$ to obtain a maximal subnormal series of $G.$

Our only remaining task is to check that $N_{j + 1} / N_j$ is an abelian group. By hypothesis, $K_{j + 1} / K_j$ is abelian, so by the Third Isomorphism Theorem, we find that $K_{j + 1} / K_j = (N_{j + 1} / H_i)/(N_j / H_i) \cong N_{j + 1} / N_j$ is likewise abelian, as desired.

Comment: This seems fine when the groups are finite, but that is not specified in the question. (Perhaps it should be?). When the group is infinite I can't see how to make your argument work, even with $G=\mathbb{Z}$ with subnormal series-with-ab-quots $\{0\}\subset\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: That's right, ${\mathbb Z}$ under addition has no composition series, but it is certainly solvable.

Comment: This answer would be fine/salvageable if it made clear that it works precisely when the groups are finite. (It works precisely when abelian factor groups each have a composition series, and hence [when these factor groups are finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/190000/10513), and hence when the group itself is finite.)

Comment: The confusion arises partly because the definition with composition series is often used in Galois Theory, but that is concerned with finite groups.

Comment: These are fair points. I had implicitly assumed that $G$ was finite. I have edited my answer to address these concerns.

Answer (score 10):

The definition involving composition series only works for finite groups, so it is just plain wrong as a definition of solvable groups. The group $({\mathbb Z},+)$ is abelian and solvable but has no composition series.

There are two equivalent definitions. Let's call a series $1=N_0 \le N_1 \le N_2 \le \cdots \le N_k=G$ *normal* if all $N_i \unlhd G$ and *subnormal* if each $N_{i-1} \unlhd N_i$.

Then a group is solvable if and only if it has a normal series with abelian factors. But this is equivalent to the condition that it has a subnormal series with abelian factors.

To see that, note that if it has a subnormal series with abelian factors, then the derived series of $G$ is a normal series with abelian factors.